# Group by Month in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have expense details in which I want to group the expenses by month and return the month and expense for that particular month. I even checked the Mongoose docs, for aggregating based on the month but my data doesn't match their standard since I am saving date like **12-Jan-2018**

. Is there a way which is possible for me to get the Month and the total amount for that month.

I want something like -  Jan : 50 , Feb : 45 and so on...

Below is the Sample Collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5babee47a7d56e5fb896f181"
    },
    "date": "07-Sep-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Starbucks",
    "category": "Restaurants",
    "amount": 18
    },
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bac361597bc8758fc065241"
    },
    "date": "01-Aug-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Michael kors bag",
    "category": "Shopping",
    "amount": 91
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5baceaafc420d147806a8038"
    },
    "date": "14-Sep-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Gift",
    "category": "Miscellaneous",
    "amount": 100
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) for index 1 to return month value.

```
db.colname.aggregate(
[
   {"$group":{
      "_id":{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$split":["$date","-"]},1]},
      "total":{"$sum":"$amount"}
   }}
 ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks it's working as expected

Answer (score 4):

You can try below aggregation with mongodb **4.0** using [**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$month": { "$toDate": "$date" }},
    "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
  }}
])
```

Or with mongodb **3.6** and above using [**`$dateFromString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$month": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}},
    "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: The first one didn't work, I was getting **Unrecognized expression '$toDate'**. The second one works almost except I want to get the Month name instead of Month number because I have to display the month name and  total amount spent in UI  `[ { _id: 10, total: 120 },
  { _id: 4, total: 25 },
  { _id: 9, total: 118 },
  { _id: 8, total: 91 },
  { _id: 5, total: 700 },
  { _id: 7, total: 20 } ]`

Comment: Are you using mongodb 4.0?

Comment: No, I am not using 4.0, pardon my ignorance!